# Fastlane upload_to_play_store returns an error `apkNotificationMessageKeyBundleRequiresPlaySigning`

Tags: fastlane

Fastlane builds a bundle and I can upload it manually, but if I run

```
upload_to_play_store(
    track: 'internal', 
    package_name: "package-name",
    skip_upload_apk: true
)
```

it throws the following error:

```
Google Api Error: apkNotificationMessageKeyBundleRequiresPlaySigning: 
For uploading an AppBundle you must be enrolled in Play Signing.
```

The Play Signing is enabled, I released a version after I enabled it. What may be a reason for the error?

Answer (score 0):

Enrolling in the new singing option through Google Play Console would be best.